# Нарушение анимации navigationController

Tags: анимация, navigationcontroller, ios, objective-c

Я презентую новый `viewController` через `navigationController`:

```
PTAgencyClients *pushedController = [[PTAgencyClients alloc] initWithNibName:@"PTAgencyClients"
                                                                      bundle:nil
                                                                      agency:agency];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:pushedController 
                                       animated:YES];
```

при нажатии кнопки  `back` на `navigationController`'е получаю странное поведение. Неустановленной очередностью возврат происходит либо мгновенно (как если бы атрибут `animated` был бы выставлен в `NO`) или наезжает сверху вниз, но не слева направо как обычно осуществляет свой переход к предыдущему `viewController`'у `navigationController`.
Время от времени вижу в консоли:

> Unbalanced calls to begin/end
> appearance transitions for PTAgencyClients: 0x6e7e0a0

гугление подсказывает убрать существующую анимацию чтобы не мешать `navigationController`'у выполнить свою, или выставить атрибут `animated` в `NO`. Я проверяю все на наличие анимаций и не нахожу их, `QuartzCore` также не использую.

[viewController с которого осуществляется переход (через -clientsButtonPressed:)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99736519/PTAgencyDetail.m)

[viewController на который осуществляется переход(с back кнопкой на navigationController'е)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99736519/PTAgencyClients.m)

Comment: это основной навигейшен контроллер в иерархии?

Comment: нет. Основной на фоне, на открытом (правом) контроллере - дочерний : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99736519/Screen%20Shot%202013-08-23%20at%2011.18.34%20AM.png

Comment: Хм, тяжело сказать навскидку. Есть какие-то шаги для воспроизведения?

Comment: в общем любой переход на прежний viewController из этого места инициирует неправильную анимацию. Причем в двух видах а нормальный вариант не удается воспроизвести вообще. Если кого-то есть время поглядеть, могу прикрепить .m файлы обоих viewController'ов к вопросу. Или могу снять на видео процесс анимации если я непонятно объяснил

Comment: показать код обоих контроллеров всегда полезно, а лучше где-то прикрепить проект

Comment: @AlexThumb, вы б хоть имена затерли ;)

Comment: Кнопка "Назад" в PTAgencyClients по умолчанию, и у нее нет анимации. Нужно переписать ее функционал, который собственно был закоментирован. Это поправит анимацию.
Почему появляется ошибка в консоле - это нужно Debug делать. В тексте разглядеть тяжело.

Comment: это уже я закомментировал этот код для кнопки. Но это ни на что не повлияло

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. То как контроллер добавляется в навигатор и как из него удаляется - разные вещи. В обоих случаях можно указывать разное поведение. Судя по всему анимации при нажатии на кнопку "Назад" нет.
2. Ошибка, которая появляется в консоли может быть по нескольким причинам:
3. возможно, что в контроллере есть метод, в котором что-то происходит:

   -(void)beginAppearanceTransition:(BOOL)isAppearing animated:(BOOL)animated
4. возможно, что новый контроллер появляется прежде, чем заканчивает работу предыдущий.